# Starting Angular

Tags: angular, filter, sql-order-by

Beginner Angular, I can not get what I want, I start by presenting my entries:

```
{"composants" : [
    {"typeCarte" : "type1", "direction":"0", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"},
    {"typeCarte" : "type1", "direction":"1", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"},
    {"typeCarte" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
    {"typeCarte" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
    {"typeCarte" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
    {"typeCarte" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
    {"typeCarte" : "type1", "direction":"0", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"},
    {"typeCarte" : "type1", "direction":"1", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"}
]}
```

NB: This represents 3 cards: 2 of type 1 (2 ports), and 1 of type 2

With this kind of entry, I would like to create this form with a display of this style, by cards:

```
    Configuration :
        Insert :

            Carte 1
            'checkbox' Port0    'checkbox' Port1 (disable)

            Carte 2
            'checkbox' Port2    'checkbox' Port3    'checkbox' Port4    'checkbox' Port5

            Carte 3
            'checkbox' Port6    'checkbox' Port7 (disable)


        Extract :

            Carte 1
            'checkbox' Port0 (disable)   'checkbox' Port1

            Carte 2
            'checkbox' Port2    'checkbox' Port3    'checkbox' Port4    'checkbox' Port5

            Carte 3
            'checkbox' Port6 (disable)    'checkbox' Port7
```

- It is necessary to be able to detect / separate the different cards (I know the a priori: {card of type 1 = 2 ports} and {card of type2 = 4 ports})
- It must be possible to offer the possibility of ticking only one box (or 0) in Insert
- It must be possible to offer the possibility of only ticking one or two boxes in Extract (or 0)

Comment: On suppose que les questions doit être écrites en anglais.

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: translated by Google, corrected formatting

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, to have some help, I also did the traduction :

```
      I am starting with angular, and I have some difficulties with it :-/ I'll first present yous my data :

        {"cardType" : "type1", "direction":"0", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"},
        {"cardType" : "type1", "direction":"1", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"},
        {"cardType" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
        {"cardType" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
        {"cardType" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
        {"cardType" : "type2", "direction":"2", "fortmats":"jpeg;bmp;png;gif"},
        {"cardType" : "type1", "direction":"0", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"},
        {"cardType" : "type1", "direction":"1", "fortmats":"jpeg;png;gif"}
    ]}

    NB : Cela représente 3 cartes, 2 de type 1 (2 ports), et 1 de type 2
    NB : These are 3 cards, 2 of the first type (2 ports) and 1 of the first one.

    With this kind of inputs, I would like to create this formular with this style, by cards :

    Configuration :
        Insert :

            Card 1
            'checkbox' Port0    'checkbox' Port1 (disable)

            Card 2
            'checkbox' Port2    'checkbox' Port3    'checkbox' Port4    'checkbox' Port5

            Card 3
            'checkbox' Port6    'checkbox' Port7 (disable)


        Extract :

            Card 1
            'checkbox' Port0 (disable)   'checkbox' Port1

            Card 2
            'checkbox' Port2    'checkbox' Port3    'checkbox' Port4    'checkbox' Port5

            Card 3
            'checkbox' Port6 (disable)    'checkbox' Port7 

    I need to detect/separate the differents cards (a priori : type1's cards = 2 ports ; type2's port = 4 ports)
    I need to propose only one case maximum in the insert part and two maximum in the extract part.

    And I need help with Angular : filters, filters creations... working with the controller ?
```